# Find Relativepaths of folders and subfolders(not files) recursively with size?

Tags: powershell

I was tried to find the relative paths of folders and subfolders (not files ) with length but i did'n get the length.

```
$srcpth = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" 
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpth -Directory -Recurse
$result = foreach ($f in $files) {
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        RelativePath =  $f.fullname.remove(0,($srcpth.length))
        FileSize     =  '{0:N1}' -f ($f_.Length/1KB)
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv "c:\files\o2.csv"
```

I tried this snippet it is showing folders and subfolders in relativepaths but its not showing their length  .anyone help me on this?

Comment: You need to get the sum of the **files** .Length properties in each folder. Have a look at [Measure-Object Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-measure-the-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: can you please give me the snippet?

Comment: Use Where-Object :  Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp | Where-Object {$_.Length -lt  1000 }

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you need for each of the directories calculate the sum of the **file** sizes in there.

Try

```
$srcpth = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" 
$files  = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpth -Directory -Recurse
$result = foreach ($f in $files) {
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        RelativePath =  $f.FullName.Remove(0, $srcpth.Length )
        FileSize     =  '{0:N1}' -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $f.FullName -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1KB)
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv "c:\files\o2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: it is not showing proper size .can u chech this code once!

Comment: @karthik You can add `-Recurse` just in front of `| Measure-Object` is that what you expect to see?

Comment: how can i get filesize in descending order?

Comment: @karthik Use [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) with switch `-Descending`